# How do I fix Error: spawn UNKNOWN with node.js v7.8.0 on windows 10?

Tags: node.js, windows

I'm getting an error on windows 10 when I try to run `spawn`

```
  var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  var child = spawn(path.join(__dirname, '../bin/run.js'), {}, {env: env});
  child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
  child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

Here is the error message. I couldn't find much about resolving this issue.

`[14:58:15] Error: spawn UNKNOWN`

I installed node with `nvs` which appears to be working fine for everything else.

So I figured out its the `run.js` which is a node script with a shebang, but that doesn't work on windows.

I tried changing it to `spawn('node run.js')` but now I get NOENT.

Comment: is NodeJS configured correctly in environmental path ?!  when you run `node ../bin/run.js` what happens?

Comment: Can you add full error message with stack trace?  That might help.

Comment: had to pass array of args. posted answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had to pass an array of args to `node`. On windows shebang lines don't work so the command I'm executing is actually `node` and the path to the `run.js` is an argument.

`spawn('node', ['run.js'])` works.

Comment: Where should  I put the code in?